# iOS universal app test on older iOS device

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios, universal

I have an iOS 4.2 universal app. I've tested the app against all available simulators (iPhone 4.0, 4.2 and 4.2; iPad 3.2 and 4.2). Everything runs great on these simulators and on real devices with iOS 4.2 (iPad 4.2 and iPhone 4.0).

The problem I am running into is while testing the application (from Xcode) on a device with pre 4.0 iOS---iPhone 3.x. The error is that it fails to run the application with:

`dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPopoverController`

The application builds with no erros (base SDK is still 4.2), installs okay but crashes while being launched. I have been careful in placing all iPhone only code in /iPhone folder/group, iPad only in /iPad folder/group and all shared libraries and views in /Shared. Furthermore, the application runs with no error on my iPhone with iOS 4.0. The UIPopoverController is never used/called from the iPhone nib so I am at a lose as to what is causing this. I am looking into adding a new target that doesn't include any of the post iOS 3.2 additions. Any help on this in the meantime would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch your compiler to LLVM GCC 4.2 and follow all the other steps in this blog post by Marco Arment: [Supporting older versions of iOS while using new APIs](http://www.marco.org/1648550153).

Comment: Thanks ... I needed to select LLVM GCC 4.2 as the compiler.